# Why is printf only printing the first char of this array and not all of them?

Tags: c

```
char *member[8];
char *tag;// this points a lot of text. if i print htmtag, it works fine with a few lines of text printing out

for ( int x = 0; x < 8; x++ )
{
    member[x] = tag[x+15];
}
printf("member: %s",member);
```

Why would the above only print out the first char in member and not the whole 7, if i printf on member[0]/member[1]/member[2] the values are stored there but the following is printed?

i.e

```
member: 1
```

and i wanted to print out

```
member: 1234567
```

Comment: Show us complete code. What's `tag` and `member` defined as. Any `wchar_t` or MS `TCHAR` perhaps?

Comment: We need the definition of `member` and `tag`.

Comment: Updated! Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**. Assigning a `char` (`tag[x+15]`) to a `char*` (`member[x]`) must make your compiler emit a diagnostic.

Comment: This is not directly related to your problem, but ensure that after your for loop `member` is NULL terminated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

member should be declared as:

```
char member[8];
```

not

```
char * member[8];
```

as it is an array of chars, not an array of char pointers

Answer (score 6):

As you didn't post enough code, the following is a *guess*:

Your `member` variable is not a `char[]` but a `wchar_t[]` or MS `TCHAR[]`. That would make each element of the `member` array larger than 1 char, so when `printf` treats it as an array of char it'd see `'1', '\0', '2', '\0'` and so on - printing the first `1` then stopping on the 0-byte.